# Connect spring boot and mongodb on different kubernetes pods

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kubernetes

I am trying to create two different deployments using kubernetes, one for a spring boot project and another one for mongo db. I want the spring boot project to connect to mongo. Here is my properties file:

```yaml
server:
  port: 8081

spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: mongo-service
      port: 27017
      database: inventory
```

And here is the .yml file I am using for kubernetes:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: inventory
  labels:
    app: inventory
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: inventory
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: inventory
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: carlospalma03/inventory_java-api:version7
        name: inventory-api
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo
  labels:
    app: mongo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mongo
        name: mongo-db
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-service
  labels:
    run: mongo-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: mongo-service
```

I get the following exception on the spring boot side:

```
Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server mongo-db:27017
```

Does anybody know what's the proper name I should use for the mongo-db service so that the spring boot project can communicate with it?

I am trying to use the name of the kubernetes service I created to enable communication but something tells me that there's a trick to how spring boot names the other pods.

Comment: The Service name `mongo-service` should be correct; that matches your properties file but not your error message.  Do you know where the name `mongo-db` is coming from?  The other potential problem is that the Service's `selector:` doesn't match the Pod's (Deployment `template:`) `labels:` field, so the Service might not actually be connected to the Pod.

Comment: Hello David, I just changed the service  to use  selector:
    app: mongo but the error persists. No idea where the mongo-db name is coming from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, a couple things here, first of all I had to create two services, not just one. The service associated to the spring boot deployment talks with other pods in the kubernetes cluster.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: inventory
  labels:
    app: inventory
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: inventory
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: inventory
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: carlospalma03/inventory_java-api:version9
        name: inventory-api
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo
  labels:
    app: mongo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mongo
        name: mongo-db
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: inventory-service
  labels:
    run: inventory-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: inventory
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-service
  labels:
    run: mongo-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: mongo
```

Secondly I had to use the spring.data.mongo.db.uri property inside the spring boot project like this:

```
server:
  port: 8081

spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb://mongo-service:27017/inventory
```